# GitHub for Mac client... doesn't allow edit repo name or description

Tags: github, github-for-mac

Once you drag and drop a new folder into GitHub for Mac, it creates a new repo. But you never have the ability to go back and change the name and description. And desctiption just shows up as "No description" Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The way you change the description is by editing the description file inside the .git folder.